# How to solve qrc image paths for qml prototyping project

Tags: qt, qml

It would be very useful to me to open my qml part of my **c++/qml** project via qml prototyping project. When I tried to do this almost everything was perfect except one think:

There were a lot of warnings regarding with images like

> "file:///D:/my/dir/with/qml/MyButton.qml:23:17: QML BorderImage:
>   Cannot open: qrc:/res/images/buttons/background-button-icon.svg"

**Is there some way to solve this problem with the current image paths?**

Here is my prototype project file:
// qmlPrototyping.qmlproject

```
import QmlProject 1.1

Project {
    mainFile: "D:\\my\\dir\\with\\qml\\MyMainQmlWnd.qml"


    /* Include .qml, .js, and image files from current directory and subdirectories */
    QmlFiles {
        directory: "D:\\my\\dir\\with\\qml\\."
    }
    JavaScriptFiles {
        directory: "D:\\my\\dir\\with\\js\\."
    }
    ImageFiles {
        directory: "D:\\my\\dir\\with\\images\\."
    }

    /* List of plugin directories passed to QML runtime */
    // importPaths: [ "../exampleplugin" ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the line of code that sets the image source? You might be able to get it work if you don't specify the qrc prefix for the images: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-networktransparency.html

Comment: I have specified
source: "qrc:/res/images/image.svg"

Comment: I use qrc file in the project and my question is could be the path like  "qrc:/res/images/image.svg" be solved in prototype project?

Comment: As I said, try removing `qrc:/` from the string. That might allow it to work in both types of projects.